# Allocating memory within remapped address range

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I'm writing a character driver which acts are bridge b/w mailbox framework and expose fops for userspace applications.
The user apps do data xfer to remote processors using this char driver. However, a requirement is remote processor wants the data to be in a fixed memory range. The range is provided to char drv in *probe()* fn.
I could do *memremap()* of the addr range provided and use it if there was a single user application but in my current case I'm having multiple applications trying to send data buffers to remote core.
So, I need to have the allocation for kernel buffer in a specific memory range and then do *copy_from_user()* on each data buffer received, then pass the physical addr to the remote core(arm m0+)

Are there any APIs in Linux kernel which does this kind of allocations?

Any pointers on this would be very much appreciated and helpful. Thanks in advance for any suggestions/questions.

ps: the memory addr range provided by remote core is a RAM addr within lower 2GB range(0x8000_0000 - 0xFFFF_FFFF)

Comment: You kernel driver for remote processor should serialize accesses and provide that fixed memory region.

Comment: Have you looked at the mempool framework?  See https://lwn.net/Articles/22909/

Comment: Thanks @0andriy, but for every application's request the remote processor has to allocate memory and will also have to maintain the allocation. I don't want the m0+ core to maintain the allocations and freeing of memory. I feel it will be overburden to remote core which is going to run small RTOS

Comment: Thanks @sawdust, I actually found the general purpose allocator(genalloc) here https://lwn.net/Articles/729653/. So, basically, m0 core gives a fixed range memory. and on Linux side i do memremap() and get the allocations to work. However, i ran into other caching issues. The m0 core is doing uncached access to memory, While the Linux side is doing cached access, I could use cache flush APIs but I'm looking for "how to map the RAM memory uncached" on Linux"

Comment: `memremap_uc()` ?

Comment: @0andriy I'm not sure if memremap_uc() is available in kernel.

Comment: *"how to map the RAM memory uncached" on Linux"* -- First of all make sure that the memory used for this pool is not part of system memory, i.e. this RAM has been excluded from the 'memory' specification in the kernel command line or Device Tree.  IOW avoid double mapping.  BTW the *"lower 2GB range"* would *not* be *"0x8000_0000 - 0xFFFF_FFFF"*.

Comment: It is, but in a form of a flag that passed to `memremap()` call. Read documentation.

Comment: Yes, I tried memremap() to have uncached mapping with MEMREMAP_WT(write through cache) flag but memremap() wasn't able to map SystemRAM address range as uncached. After carving out this memory range memremap() worked and i have uncached memory range.

Comment: Thanks sawdust, 0andriy for you help.